# jquery lightbox, flickrpress, combo not working on a wordpress site?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site that uses the flickrpress plugin and jquery lightbox plugin to display a gallery of images, it works fine on the first page but on the next page doesn't launch jquery, really not sure why? Here's a link to the page http://bit.ly/herSaZ

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you load new html content after lightbox is initialized as you are doing via AJAX, that new content won't go through the lightbox functions at anytime. It's a guess, but it makes sense to me.

I didn't test this, but what if you try adding a hardcoded link to the thumbs: `<a onclick="lightbox.start(this); return false;" >`? This way the problem shouldn't occur, if it indeed this is the error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the line to the <a> tag to no avail? Also the plugin used to work not sure why it would change.

Comment: I see the onclick added, but `lightbox` is not defined, so it won't work just like that, you have to define it with: `lightbox = new jQuery.LightboxClass` in a script tag in the head, after the lightbox plugin is loaded. Do you use firebug? I tried it with it and it works, although it seems to have problems finding the img.

Comment: Thanks AJweb, but what would the full code be to define the lightbox function? I kind of get but I'm not sure how I would wrap the definition?

Comment: @Nsokyi, For my tests I added the definition directly on Firebug's console, but if you just add this: `<script type="text/javascript">lightbox = new jQuery.LightboxClass;</script>` at the end of your html head, the onclick code that you already have in place should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the definition in, but now I see what you mean about the problem in getting the img. Firebug is giving me a hole bunch of jquery warnings but I'm not sure which one is the main problem and they seem to change every time I reload the page?